# Type of Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts.EventTelemetry.Properties

Tags: azure-application-insights

I am using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.dll for net45 from package 2.5.1 in Powershell. weird thing is that the type of EventTelemetry.Properties change between ConcurrentDictionary and Dictionary.

if it is ConcurrentDictionary, everything works fine, but if it is Dictionary, it doesn't save customDimentions and customMeasurement.

here is the script I used:

```
$AI = "C:\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.dll"    
$null = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($AI)
$InstrumentationKey = "XXXXX"
$TelClient = New-Object "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryClient"
$TelClient.InstrumentationKey = $InstrumentationKey 

$EventTelemetry  = New-Object "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts.EventTelemetry"
```

Comment: The interfaces all specify `IDictionary`, but the implementation of dictionary used is `ConcurrentDictionary` to be thread safe, etc.  given i don't see you using either directly in your code above.  so what specific problem does this cause?

Comment: the problem is that sometimes the $EventTelemetry.Properties is a dictionay, sometimes it is ConcurrentDictionary, and I don't have control on this. When it is Dictionary, the data I saved to properties is not save  somehow.

Comment: if it is sometimes one and sometimes the other, are you getting different versions of the ai assemblies loading on different places/machines/etc?  the underlying implementation uses concurrentdictionary so it should always be concurrentdictionary unless something else is overwriting them

Comment: same machine, same place. I don't know what could cause it use Dictionary. I couldn't reproduce it consistently.

Comment: then the best place to post about this is the GitHub issues page for the AI .net sdk itself: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues